# How can write function inside execute key in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, stored-functions

```
Create Function fnRMatrixColorGet1(
@RMID varchar(20)
)
returns varchar(100)

as
begin

EXEC (N'SELECT ' + 'C'+@RMID + ' FROM vwemployeeget where empid='+@RMID) 
return 
end
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Functions in SQL Server cannot execute dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon wrote in the comments, user defined functions in SQL Server can't execute dynamic SQL.

From [Create User-defined Functions:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

> - User-defined functions cannot make use of dynamic SQL or temp tables. Table variables are allowed.

However, you can create a stored procedure to do that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stpRMatrixColorGet1
(
    @RMID varchar(20)
    @MatrixColor varchar(100) OUTPUT
)
AS

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(4000),
        @Column sysname = N'C' + @RMID;

-- White list column name since it can't be parameterized
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Information_Schema.Columns
    WHERE Table_Name = 'vwemployeeget'
    AND Column_Name = @Column
)
BEGIN

    SET @SQL = N'SELECT @MatrixColor = QUOTENAME('+ @Column +') FROM vwemployeeget where empid = @RMID'

    -- Safely execute dynamic SQL using sp_ExecuteSql
    EXEC sp_ExecuteSql 
                        @Sql, 
                        N'@RMID varchar(20), @MatrixColor varchar(100) OUTPUT', 
                        @RMID, 
                        @MatrixColor OUTPUT
END
```

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)